# Cloud9 python version for pylint/jedi

Tags: python, cloud9-ide

I have installed python3.8 with yum and set it as the default with update-alternatives.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install python3.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
```

Run works correctly but jedi insists on using Python3.7 and provides autocomplete/linting based on wrong version of stdlib.

AFAICT c9 seems hardcoded to run integrated jedi with `~/.c9/python3/bin/python3` and typechecking/navigation works against wrong version.

Is there a way to override it?

Comment: Yes. there is a way, check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76631257/20364896 :)