# How to install python3.11 and update Pylint on Amazon Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, cloud9-ide, cloud9, amazon-linux-2

How to install python3.11 on Amazon Cloud9 IDE? and make the IDE's Pylint module recognize Python's new feature/keywords, such as "match"?

Is there any simpler solutions?

## I have found a solution with following steps:

**Step One: install python3.11**

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum erase openssl-devel -y
sudo yum install openssl11 openssl11-devel  libffi-devel bzip2-devel wget -y
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.11.4.tgz
cd Python-3.11.4/
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-optimizations
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make altinstall
python3.11 -V
```

NOTE: make -j $(nproc) This command will take a long time to complete. Please be patient.

**Step Two: install pip**

```
sudo yum install python3-pip
```

**Step Three: install pylint**

```
sudo yum makecache
sudo yum -y install pylint
```

**Step Four: Switch python3 from python3.x to python3.11**

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3
```

NOTE: The path might be different.

Congratulations! Python3.11 is installed.

Let's test it

In the IDE create a file test.py with two lines of code

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

On the menu bar, click Run > Run With > Python 3, then python version will show, such as:

3.11.4

**Step Five: Give the IDE a new Pylint**

Now we need to get the Pylint working too, for proper error checking.

Open the pylint file.

```
vi ~/.c9/python3/bin/pylint
```

Change the very first line to following

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.11
```

NOTE: The path of python3.11 might be different

And save

Sometimes it won’t take effect immediately, just close all the tabs(files) on the IDE and reopen again.

**Congratulations, Again! All done**

let's try python’s new match pattern feature

```
def color(color):
    match color:
        case "red":
            print("I am red")
        case "blue":
            print("I am blue")
        case _:
            print("I am blank")
             
color("red")
color("blue")
color("love")
```

Comment: Works like magic! Thank you for sharing. I only had a little issue adjusting pip, but running this command after all of your commands solved it:

`sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Please post the solution you included in your question as an answer. Then accept your own answer. So that people could see that the questions was answered and could upvote the answer as well.